# How to connect to existing oracle db table in Django

Tags: python, django, oracle

Actually, i am developing UI for my team for daily Data visualization using Django, but from last two week i have searched a lot in google, i didn't get solution, even i have followed Django Documentation for connecting Oracle DB.

**Already i have date in my Metrics table, i don't want create a table again. can anyone help me to connect existing Oracle DB OtherUser table in Django and how to write in model.py.**

i have installed cx_Oracle library also.

i have tried inspectin DB its show as below.

**from django.db import models**

**Unable to inspect table 'METRICS'**

**The error was: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

```
# setting.py

'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
    'NAME': 'servicename',
    'USER': 'mysuer',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'SCHEMAS': 'SCHEMANAME',
}
```

```
# models.py

class Metrics(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = '"SCHEMANAME"."METRICS"'
        verbose_name = 'Metrics'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Metrics'
```

i have test in single test.py file i am able to get the data using cursor in cx_oracle, but how i can do it in django?

Comment: If all else fails, there's a very old Django & Oracle tutorial at https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/oow10/python_django/python_django.htm

Comment: i have already tried posted in above link, getting ORA-00904: "SCHEMANAME"."METRICS"."ID": invalid identifier, I don't wanna create a new table, i want access data from existing table. Is there any other workaround..?